# Can chiral atoms have same substituents but with different orientations?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, stereochemistry

So consider this molecule. We have to determine whether nitrogen atom is chiral or not.
[image]

**MY IDEAS:** 
Now going by all I have read, for chiral atoms only criteria is **substituents to be different.** Here two substituents are same but as we can see orientations of the substituents is different.
So aren't the two substituents technically different because after all **they aren't going to react the same way to plane polarized light?**

*I tried to break it into possibilities:*
[image]
Now in first case I think we could rotate around one of the sigma bonds attached to nitrogen and form a **conformation** with a plane of symmetry.
So is in this case nitrogen not a chiral atom? 
[image]
Now in the second case I do think we can't prove the two substituents to be same, no matter how much we rotate. So chiral?

***CONCLUSION***: I am a beginner in this topic and not really confident about my thought process

Can we really *use conformers of molecules to support their symmetry because after all* conformers are ever changing, not stuck in one orientation?

Also what's the *logic behind checking the plane and centre of symmetry of molecules*? How does that relate to rotation of PPL light?

->If two substituents of a sp3 hybridized atom are identical, we say not optically active.
 But ***both being identical will rotate PPL light in same direction, so a net rotation will be produced.*** 
->So isn't it optically active?

Comment: So, where did you find this tetravalent nitrogen atom? ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not an asymmetric centre. To test this, you can draw the two potential stereoisomers:

[image: isomers]

Note that isomers A and B are identical (by C2 rotation), so the nitrogen cannot be an asymmetric centre. If it were one, then these isomers would by definition be distinct.

The attached groups *are* identical, from the point of view of the nitrogen - both have (R) stereochemistry. If one were (R) and the other (S), the nitrogen would constitute a *pseudoasymmetric centre* - https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/P/P04921.html

Hope this helps.

Also, don't get confused about the difference between the nitrogen being a sterogenic centre, and the molecule as a whole being chiral. The molecule *is* chiral, since it is non-superimposable on its mirror image. Chirality is a *molecular* property, and although frequently people will refer to a particular atom in a molecule as "chiral", this is a misnomer. A better description of an atom with 4 different groups attached is "sterogenic". It is entirely possible to have a molecule containing stereogenic centres but the molecule is achiral (e.g. *meso* compounds).

The logic behind checking the plane and centre of symmetry is that planes and centres of symmetry are conserved on reflection in a mirror, so checking for these symmetry elements is a shortcut to checking whether a molecule satisfies the definition of chirality.

Comment: Please could you help with what's wrong with my ideas

Comment: Part of your issue is in distinguishing the difference between configuration and conformation. The configuration of a molecule is the description of which atoms are bonded to which, and in what 3D arrangement around each atom. You can only change configuration by breaking or making bonds. Conformations are just different arrangements of atoms achieved by rotating around the single bonds in the molecule. Stereochemistry concerns configuration only, not conformation.

Comment: In the current case, look at the two alcohol stereocentres and define them as (R) or (S) - you should find that both are (R). So, from the point of view of the nitrogen atom, it is attached to X, Y and two identical, (R)-configured groups. Since two of the groups attached to the tetrahedral N are identical, it is not a stereogenic centre.

Comment: But remember this is only to tell whether the nitrogen atom is stereogenic, it says nothing about whether the molecule as a whole is chiral. The gold standard test for that is always to draw its mirror image and check whether it is possible to superimpose the two.